# For loop running only once in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I've just started shell scripting.
Here is my code:

```
read totalNumbers

for i in {1..$totalNumbers..1}
do
  echo "Welcome $i times"   
done
```

When the input is given as 100, I'm getting the output as

```
Welcome {1..100..1} times
```

But I need something like

```
Welcome 1 times

Welcome 2 times

Welcome 3 times

.

.

.

Welcome 100 times
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use variable names inside `{..}` in shell.

You can use `((..))` for arithmetic in BASH:

```
for (( i=1; i <= $totalNumbers; i++ )); do
  echo "Welcome $i times"   
done
```

Even `for (( i=1; i <= totalNumbers; i++ ))` would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use

```
{1..$totalNumbers..1}
```

anyway, replace it by

```
$(eval echo {1..$totalNumbers..1})
```

---

`$(...)` runs a subshell.